# <object> and <embed> do not recalculate width when the height is strictly given in CSS

Tags: object, embed, dimensions

I have a flash stuff on a web page, which height I want to control basing on parent's explicitly set height. Width should be recalculated to preserve proportions - as it happens when dealing with `<img>` tag:

```
<div>
    <object>
      <embed src="..."> <!-- no attributes except src -->
  </object>
</div>

<style>
    div { height: 300px; }
    object, embed { height: 100%;   }
</style>
```

Instead of expected behaviour I get the flash of absolutely other size: it is much smaller than it's parent in all dimensions. Actually, I don't understand why it takes this particular size - it looks too small (like zoomed out few times).

To make it to behave in a proper way I have to set both width and height for  explicitly. It may be done both inline and in CSS.

**The question is: why doesn't it calculate height** (though it obviously has enough data - `<img>` can resize properly at the same conditions) **based on parent's height and given percentage?**.

(Initially I've had many other attributes (including duplicated width and height on both  and  tags) which all I removed to simplify the example. While doing that, I was checking whether removement changes anything and it didn't except of width and height attributes.)